# Mongodb MapReduce performance using Indexes

Tags: mongodb

I have a sample document in mongodb(and I am still new to mongodb)

```
{
    "ID": 0,
    "Facet1":"Value1",
    "Facet2":[
        {
            "Facet2Obj1":{
                "Obj1Facet1":"Value11",
                "Obj2Facet1":"Value21",
                "Obj3Facet1":"Value31"
            }   
        },
        {
            "Facet2Obj2":{
                "Obj1Facet2":"Value12",
                "Obj2Facet2":"Value22",
                "Obj3Facet2":"Value32"
            }
        },
        {
            "Facet2Obj3":{
                "Obj1Facet3":"Value13",
                "Obj2Facet3":"Value23",
                "Obj3Facet3":"Value33"
            }
        }
    ],
    "Facet3":"Value3"
    "Facet4":{
        "Facet4Obj1":{
            "Obj1Facet1":"Value4111"
        }
    }
}
```

The Mapreduce is a little bit complex and it gives the following ouput(for 30,000 documents):

```
{
    "_id" : "Facet1",
    "value" : [
        {
            "value" : "Value1",
            "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
            .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "ID",
    "value" : [
        {
            "value" : 0,
            "count" : 1,
            "ID" : [
                0
            ]
        },
        {
            "value" : 1,
            "count" : 1,
            "ID" : [
                1
            ]
        },
        .
        .
        .
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "Facet2",
    "value" : [
        {
            "value" : "Facet2Obj1",
            "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        },
        {
            "value" : "Facet2Obj2",
            "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        },
        {
            "value" : "Facet2Obj3",
            "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "Facet3",
    "value" : [
    {
            "value" : "Value3",
        "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
                2,
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
    ]
} 
{
    "_id" : "Facet4",
    "value" : [
        {
            "value" : "Facet4Obj1",
            "count" : 30000,
            "ID" : [
                0,
                1,
                2,
                .
                .
                .
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I inserted 30,000 documents using the format(with different IDs) into the mongodb, Then I did a map-reduce,but it was slow. With 30,000 documents it will take about 30 minutes , but then I put indexes with the facets it became faster a little bit, like it would take 350 seconds but with 50,000 documents it took again about 30 minutes. When I check the indexes using `db.collection.getIndexes()` mongodb will return this output:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "_id" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "database.collection",
    "name" : "_id_"
},
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "ID" : 1,
        "Facet1" : 1,
        "Facet2" : 1,
        "Facet3" : 1,
        "Facet4" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "database.collection",
    "name" : "ID_1_Facet1_1_Facet2_1_Facet3_1_Facet4_1"
}
```

Is there anything I did wrong with the indexes that the map-reduce is still not fast enough because Indexes must be strategically place or performance output will be the opposite

Answers are greatly appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: MR cannot use indexes

Comment: What is the query that you are passing to mapReduce?  And what are you doing with mapReduce in general?  It's always going to be slower than aggregation or other types of operations that run in the server rather than in Javascript

Comment: If MR cannot use indexes then why it became faster a little bit? , there is no query used, so all of the 30,000 documents is passed to the mapreduce. Yes there are topics about the performance of the mapreduce but does 50,000 documents is not that big enough to make mapreduce for about half an hour? or does it depends on how complex the mapreduce work is done?

Comment: or does the indexing is not correct?

Comment: two more quick comments: your Facet4 single embedded document where Facet1 has array of documents.  If Facet4 can also be an array of documents, make sure if there is just one you inserted it as array of one or it'll be harder to process later.  The other comment is a compound index on four fields would normally be added if you have queries for all fields - and indexing on things that are themselves objects/subdocuments is seldom right as it only matches a query where you provide full document for the match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MapReduce passes every document in a collection into the map function *except* if you pass it {query: } option which it will use to "pre"-filter documents sent to MapReduce.   You can also pass a {sort:} option to mapReduce and it will send documents to map function sorted on that field(s).

That's the only two places where indexes will be used - after that everything happens in the Javascript thread that's spawned for the work.

Comment: I have read a blog about using MapReduce in its full potential , one point he raised was about using the sort option, can I use the sort option in the above mapReduce format? or what part of the mapreduce operation is the sort option used? or when it is used in the process?

The format is like `{"_id":"","value":[{},{},...]}` , can I use the sort option in sorting the values inside the `value` array?

Comment: No it just indicates what order should be used when sending all documents through map function.

Comment: That is also a thing that I misunderstand , and this might be an enlightenment , thanks but I will accept this answer once I finished Implementing this.

Comment: @AsyaKamsky If you provide both a `sort` and a `query`, should you have one index with fields from the sort, then the query, one index with fields from the query, then the sort, or two indexes?

Comment: you should have one compound index in order {filterField:1,sortField:1} however, it can only be used effectively if filter is an equality (or $in or some equivalent, not if it's a range, for example).

Comment: @AsyaKamsky What if I need to use ranges in some of the query's fields? Should I include them in the compound index?

Comment: are you taking about a third field still?  probably this is complex enough that SO isn't a good discussion place for it - maybe ask on MongoDB-user google group?