# Does mongodb has some 'soft' indexing optimization?

Tags: mongodb, date, database-design

I have a 10 Go collection with pretty small documents (~1kb) which all contain the field `'date'`. I need to do some daily mapreduce over the documents, only on the last day.

I have a few options :

1. no index
2. index over 'date'
3. create a field "day" which is date without the time.
4. have one collection per day. myCollection_20140106 for instance

I am thinking of 3 because it looks to me as a good compromise for indexing (slow) and reading the entire not indexed database (slow). Sorting the array `1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3 ,1, 2` might be faster than sorting `1, 13, 2, 8, 5, 4, 6, 3, 7, 11` because there are more equal valued items. Does it apply to mongodb indexes ? Is the solution 3 good for this or is it just stupid and not faster than 2 ?

Any advice on this is most welcomed. Thank you very much!

EDIT : MR code :

```
db.my_col.mapReduce(map, reduce, {finalize: finalize, out: {merge: "day"}, 
    query: {"date": {$gte: start_date, $lt: end_date, $exists: true}}})
```

map/reduce/finalize are basic functions to compute the average of a given field over the day "group by" another field. (e.g date, name, price -> compute the average price per person for a given day). (This is not the case but you can consider it is, I think the mapReduce/query are the things of interest here and I don't want to pollute the question by adding extra weight)

Comment: Can you share your M/R job/code as well?

Comment: You're not showing the whole code - only the call to mapReduce. I think you might be better off looking at the Aggregation Framework. But the least you can do is show input documents and an expected output of M/R.

Comment: I don't see how this would help, I think my case is pretty clear as is. Do you have different answers in mind depending on what data I will show ?

Comment: Probably. The layout of your data and/or queries has great impacts on how you do certain things. Perhaps the answer could be: redesign your schema. Or not.

Comment: why would a binary sort be faster on a set of similar items? Wouldn't it actually be slower?

Comment: Also mongodb indexes come pre-sorted, aka no actual sorting is needed, if you sort against the index you actually get scanandorder problems

Comment: I would personally say the only thing 3 has over 2 is size of the index, you *might* get a negligible amount of speed from comparing a smaller long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the fact that you are using date for your initial selection criteria, having an index over date makes more sense than having an index over day. Date is superset of day values and in terms of entries they still refer to index of similar (just to be cautious, it's not same) order of magnitude.

M/R functions are not analyzed and cannot use any indexes in mongodb. However as in your case, the query and sort portion of the command can take advantage of the indexes defined in mongodb.

I would also suggest taking a look at [Mongodb MapReduce performance using Indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106869/mongodb-mapreduce-performance-using-indexes) .

Comment: I tested and it is actually the same speed to index over date or day.